# Delete multiple rows in a DF

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problems deleting many lines.

I want to delete forty lines on my Dataframe and I used this command:

```
del energy.iloc [246:]
```

to delete all lines after 246 until 283 but I received this message:

```
"AttributeError: __delitem__".
```

Can someone help me!

Thank you!

Comment: energy = energy.iloc [246:].copy()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reassign your dataframe

```
energy = energy.iloc[:246].copy()
```

Or if you prefer having more control on the indexes to delete:

```
index_to_delete = nergy.iloc[246:].index.values
energy.drop(labels=index_to_delete, inplace=True)
```